# Accordion will not work properly

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

I built a simple Accordion based on https://codepen.io/magnix/pen/OzeYmQ?limit=all&page=4&q=accordion to make sure it works and integrated carefully into my codes and it seems doesn't work. It's currently displaying the address of the high school. When the page loads it will not hide the address and when I click on the links to collapse the description - it will not work. I went to all the classes making sure theres not typos, etc. No success.

HTML

```
<ul class="linkLocation">
    <li class="linkHover is-active">
        <a href="#mapTX" class="linkThumb"> Austin, TX</a>
        <p class="accordion-panel">
        <address style="font-style: normal;">
        High School 1<br>
        1234 Congress Ave<br>
        Austin, TX 75087
        </address></p>
    </li>
    <li class="linkHover">
        <a href="#mapLA" class="linkThumb"> Shreveport, LA</a>
        <p class="accordion-panel">
        <address style="font-style: normal;">
        High School 2<br>
        1234 Congress Ave<br>
        Shreveport, LA 75087
        </address></p>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.linkThumb {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .8rem 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;

    &::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-left: .5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
    }
}
.accordion-panel {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: .8rem;
    display: none;
}
.linkHover.is-active {
.linkThumb::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
// (Optional) Active an item if it has the class "is-active"    
$(".linkLocation > .linkHover.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown();

$(".linkLocation > .linkHover").click(function() {
    // Cancel the siblings
    $(this).siblings(".linkHover").removeClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideUp();
    // Toggle the item
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideToggle("ease-out");
});
});
```

Heres the code that doesnt work - [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/gzxjqt48/9/)

Comment: From the fiddle, it looks as though you need to include jQuery.

Comment: also your fiddle trying to select based on class whereas html has ID for element <ul id="linkLocation">. Either change it to class or update JS code to read from id. e.g. $("#linkLocation > .linkHover.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown(); Probably good option is to change the id to class.

Comment: Just updated the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.accordion-panel` to a `div`. Apparently the `address` element doesn't like being inside a `paragraph` element.

```html
<div class="accordion-panel">
    <address style="font-style: normal;">
    High School<br>
    1234 Congress Ave<br>
    Austin, TX 75087
  </address>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated your code and JSFiddle. Looks like the first Accordion will not collapse only the second one

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ugrktutx/

```
<ul class="linkLocation">
  <li class="linkHover is-active"><a href="#mapTX" class="linkThumb"> Austin, TX</a>
    <div class="accordion-panel">
    <address style="font-style: normal;">
    High School<br>
    1234 Congress Ave<br>
    Austin, TX 75087
        </address></div>
  </li>
</ul>

$("#linkLocation > .linkHover.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown();
$("#linkLocation > .linkHover").click(function() {
//click code
});
```

There's couple of adjustments I have made,

1. Changed the linkLocation selector to id in js code.
2. Changed accordion-panel element to div to enclose address

Comment: I updated the code on JSFIDDLE. Looks like the first Accordion will not collapse only the second one.